# Catching "bind: address already in use"

Tags: go, error-handling, udp

I want to catch "bind: address already in use" error in golang.

```
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
if err != nil {
    if CATCH_BIND_ERROR(err) {
         // Do something if 'addr' is already in use
    } else {
         panic(err)
    }
}
```

Is there any way to implement CATCH_BIND_ERROR function?

Comment: Checking for strings is a risky idea. See and verify if something like this helps you construct the right type of error to check against what your call returns https://play.golang.org/p/pQ7tGsWYvhG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easy way is just to check the text of the error:

```
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
if err != nil && err.Error() == "bind: address already in use" {
    // Failed to bind, do something
}
if err != nil {
    // Some other error
    panic(err)
}
```

For a simple case like this, this may be sufficient. This approach is somewhat fragile, however:

1. If the library ever changes the error message (this *does* happen from time to time, although is probably unlikely in this specific instance), the check will break
2. If you do this check in some wrapping function, that may also return other types of errors, you may, at least in theory, receive a false positive, if some other functionality returns an error with the same text (also probably unlikely in this case)

To mitigate these concerns, you may be able to check for the specific error type, rather than just a textual representation. In your example, the [net](https://golang.org/pkg/net) package provides a few custom errors. The [`ListenUDP`](https://golang.org/src/net/udpsock.go?s=6818:6882#L217) method returns a [`net.OpError`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/#OpError), which means you can examine it more closely. For example:

```
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
var opErr net.OpError
if errors.As(err, &opErr) {
    if opErr.Op == "listen" && strings.Contains(opErr.Error.Error(), "address already in use") {
        // Failed to bind, do something
    }
}
if err != nil {
    // Some other error, panic
    panic(err)
}
```

Or prior to Go 1.13:

```
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
if opErr, ok := err.(*net.OpError); ok {
    if opErr.Op == "listen" && strings.Contains(opErr.Error.Error(), "address already in use") {
        // Failed to bind, do something
    }
}
if err != nil {
    // Some other error, panic
    panic(err)
}
```

In this case, we still depend on a textual check, so there's still a risk of future library changes breaking the test.  But by checking for the `net.OpError` type, we do mitigate the second risk, that some other error, with the same text, may be raised.

Comment: On Windows, the error message is "Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted." I invite you to check my solution that supports Windows. :-)

Comment: @StarBrilliant: This is a prime example why checking the text of an error message is bad practice :)

Answer (score 7):

On Windows, the error message is "`Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.`"

Additionally, in case of localization, the message would change.

Here is a possible solution to catch "Address already in use" error:

```
func isErrorAddressAlreadyInUse(err error) bool {
    errOpError, ok := err.(*net.OpError)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    errSyscallError, ok := errOpError.Err.(*os.SyscallError)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    errErrno, ok := errSyscallError.Err.(syscall.Errno)
    if !ok {
        return false
    }
    if errErrno == syscall.EADDRINUSE {
        return true
    }
    const WSAEADDRINUSE = 10048
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" && errErrno == WSAEADDRINUSE {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

To use this function:

```
conn, err := net.ListenUDP("udp", addr)
if err != nil {
    if isErrorAddressAlreadyInUse(err) {
        // Do something if 'addr' is already in use
    } else {
        panic(err)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To update Star Brilliant's most-excellent answer with Go 1.13's [error enhancements](https://blog.golang.org/go1.13-errors):

```golang
func isErrorAddressAlreadyInUse(err error) bool {
    var eOsSyscall *os.SyscallError
    if !errors.As(err, &eOsSyscall) {
        return false
    }
    var errErrno syscall.Errno // doesn't need a "*" (ptr) because it's already a ptr (uintptr)
    if !errors.As(eOsSyscall, &errErrno) {
        return false
    }
    if errErrno == syscall.EADDRINUSE {
        return true
    }
    const WSAEADDRINUSE = 10048
    if runtime.GOOS == "windows" && errErrno == WSAEADDRINUSE {
        return true
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: `errors.As()` should work fine with syscall.Errno; you just need to pass in a pointer to `syscall.Errno`, not a pointer to a pointer, because `syscall.Errno` is the type implementing `error`, not `*syscall.Errno`.


`var errErrno syscall.Errno`; `if !errors.As(eOsSyscall.Err, &errErrno) { return false }`

Comment: Thanks @thepaul, I've updated my code snippet.